# Too many $or clauses parse.com rest API

Tags: c#, json, api, rest, parse-platform

Im a newbie in this API(parse.com). And this is my first question in stackoverflow.

I currently creating a script to post sets of parameters.

This is my current code:

```
{
    "where": {
        "$or": [
            {
                "deviceType": {
                    "$in": [
                        "android",
                        "ios"
                    ]
                },
                "carMaker": 3,
                "year_from": 1981
            },
            {
                "deviceType": {
                    "$in": [
                        "android",
                        "ios"
                    ]
                },
                "carMaker": 5,
                "year_from": 1995
            }
        ]
    },
    "data": {
        "alert": "Autoparts Notification",
        "badge": "Increment",
        "sound": "cheering.caf"
    }
}
```

This one is not working and returns me error "too many $or clauses". But when I remove "year_from" it allows me to post for push notifications. Is there any way to do this? Please help me. I dont know any workarounds for this. Please tell me if I am missing anything for you to help me. Thanks in advance.